# is there an pool of connections by default in Spring Boot 2.x with HikariCP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, database-connection, hikaricp

I'm developing a web service with Spring Framework (spring boot 2.1.5), that has to generated a pool of connections (without JNDI).

I have heard that Spring Data (when the version of spring boot is higher than 2.X) implements **HikaryCP** for managing the connections, but I do know if this happen automatically or I have to activated with some configuration.

If it is true, Every services that use Spring Data, and whose version of Spring Boot is higher than 2.x, have by default a pool of connections always activated and working. is it true?

If it is true, Do Someone have any bibliography where i can read the default properties of **HikariCP**.

---------------------------------Added--------------------------

I have found the follow information in a book:

[https://books.google.com/books?id=au1mDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&dq=spring+boot+and+HikariCP&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmh4aY68vkAhUWrp4KHTbKCq4Q6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=spring%20boot%20and%20HikariCP&f=false](https://books.google.com/books?id=au1mDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&dq=spring%20boot%20and%20HikariCP&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmh4aY68vkAhUWrp4KHTbKCq4Q6AEwAXoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=spring%20boot%20and%20HikariCP&f=false)

With Spring Boot 2.0, the default basic DataSoruce initialization is only enabled for embedded database and will be disabled as soon as a production database is used. Te configuration property **spring.datasource.initialization-mode** (with values always or never), which replaces the old **spring.datasource.initialize** configuration property, can be user for more control.

Comment: I found this reference useful: https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hikaricp

Answer (score 2):

Hikari is [on by default](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hikaricp) in Spring boot 2+

> If we are using Spring Boot 2.0 and onwards, Spring Boot selects HikariDataSource by default

All hikari properties in [github](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) with full explanation

> maximumPoolSize
>   This property controls the maximum size that the pool is allowed to reach, including both idle and in-use connections. Basically this value will determine the maximum number of actual connections to the database backend. A reasonable value for this is best determined by your execution environment. When the pool reaches this size, and no idle connections are available, calls to getConnection() will block for up to connectionTimeout milliseconds before timing out. Please read about pool sizing. Default: 10

Comment: Are you sure?. I have added some import text above.

Comment: @j.abel it's about running sql on startup https://www.javaskool.com/database-initialization-in-spring-boot/